# Convert string into pre-defined int variable name

Tags: c++, debugging, struct, constructor

I am trying to access the members of object regA and object regB from within the constructor of struct BlockA. I want to be able to assign an incremented address to each regtype member of a BlockA object from the address that is assigned to the BlockA in the constructor. I want the addresses assigned to the regtype members to be incremented according to their size.

Right now, I have my constructor trying to assign an address to a string, which doesn't work, right? And I also have errors saying that in the MemberAddress function, regA and regB are undefined.

Is there a way to get the compiler to recognize the string returned by the MemberAddress function as the address of the member defined in BlockA? Pointing out other problems that you see would also be appreciated.

```
 struct RegTypeA {
    int addr ; 
    int val ;
};

 struct RegTypeB {
    int addr ; 
    int val ;
};


 struct BlockA {
    RegTypeA regA ; 
    RegTypeB regB ;
    int addr;
    BlockA(int address);

};


size_t BLOCK_STRUCT_MEMBERS_TypeSize(const unsigned int idx) {
     static const size_t sizes[] = { sizeof(RegTypeA), sizeof(RegTypeB), };
     if (idx < (sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(sizes[0]))) return sizes[idx]; 
         return 0; 
};

 const char* BLOCK_STRUCT_MEMBERS_MemberAddress(const unsigned int idx) { 
        static const char * names[] = { regA.addr, regB.addr }; 
        if (idx < (sizeof(names)/sizeof(names[0]))) return names[idx];
             return "UNKNOWN"; 
};

BlockA::BlockA(int address) {
    addr = address;
    const int y = 1 +1 +1;

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        size_t size = BLOCK_STRUCT_MEMBERS_TypeSize(i);
        std::string regaddress = BLOCK_STRUCT_MEMBERS_MemberAddress(i);
        regaddress = address;
        address = address + size;
        std::cout << address;
    }
}



int main()
{
    BlockA blockA1(3);

    std::cout << blockA1.regA.addr << std::endl << blockA1.regB.addr;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what do you need that? Chasing a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: two questions: 1) Do you know that members are stored at memory adresses with on offset relative to the instance address, e.g. `BlockA a;` then `&a == &a.regA`  and `&a + sizeof(int) + maybe some padding == &a.regB` 2) Is 1) in any way related to what you want to do? ...because tbh I dont get it at all what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
BlockA::BlockA(int address) :
    addr(address)
{
    regA.addr = address;                // regA.addr = address +  offsetof(BlockA, regA)
    regB.addr = address + sizeof(regA); // regB.addr = address +  offsetof(BlockA, regB)
}
```